# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined-IONIC2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to `push` iterated value to `array`

`json_resp` is  Json response.

my Typescript code

```
export class hello {

  CategoryLst:any[];

  var catIndex,BillerIndex;

  for(catIndex = 0; catIndex <= json_resp.category.length; catIndex++) {
    var Clst = json_resp.category[0].categoryName;
    this.CategoryLst.push(Clst);
  }
}
```

while  trying  to  execute  its  throwing  error  as

**ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

is  there  something am  i missing ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
CategoryLst:any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

`CategoryLst:any[]` is just specifying the type of the `array`, but not assigning it, so by default the value of that array would be `undefined`.

In order to initialize it in the same declaration, you should do it this way:

```
CategoryLst:any[] = [];
```